# Switch statement reverse using sed

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I have code that looks like this:

```
switch (argument0) {
    case ("Goblin"):
        return 0;
    break;
    case ("Fang"):
        return 1;
    break;
    ...
}
```

How can I, using sed or another command line tool, switch around the returns and cases so it looks like this:

```
switch (argument0) {
    case (0):
        return "Goblin";
    break;
    case (1):
        return "Fang";
    break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -vRS="^$" -vORS= '{$0=gensub(/(case \()([^)]+)(\):\s*return )(\S+);/,"\\1\\4\\3\\2;","g")}1' file  
switch (argument0) {
    case (0):
        return "Goblin";
    break;
    case (1):
        return "Fang";
    break;
    ...
}
```

Liberally sprinkle `\s*`s in the regexp if/when white space can occur.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of

```
 sed '/^[[:space:]]*case/ { N; s/case (\(.*\)):\(.* return \)\(.*\);/case (\3):\2\1;/; }' filename
```

That is:

```
/^[[:space:]]*case/ {   # in lines that bein with "case" (optionally preceded by
               # whitespace)
  N            # fetch the next line

  # Then split, reassemble.
  s/case (\(.*\)):\(.* return \)\(.*\);/case (\3):\2\1;/
}
```

Note that this will only work for code that is formatted fairly strictly like the one you showed, with the `return` directly in the line after the `case` label and parentheses just the right way.

By the way, I can't think of a reason to have `break;` directly after `return` statements in C.

Comment: break after return cleans up some lint warnings.

Comment: Gah. Mac OS X, eh? Hold on, let me boot my FreeBSD VM to make this compatible to BSD sed.

Comment: There, try again. It just needed an extra semicolon before the `}` to make BSD sed happy. BSD sed is picky like that.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. edit: or not, it seems like it just outputs the same file that I put in. Hm. :<

Comment: Oh, BSD sed doesn't seem to understand `\s`. I shall definitely have to remember that. Replacing it with `[[:space:]]` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*case/ {N;s/\(.*\)\("[^"]*"\)\(.*return \)\([^;]*\);/\1\4\3\2;/;}' YourFile
```

- same concept as @Wintermute but with other separator.
- This kind of sed could never be secure (so wide possibility of coding) but do most of the job if source file is like the sample.